# EitherT: Call function returning Either only if a certain condition is true (otherwise return right)

Tags: scala, conditional-statements, monad-transformers, scala-cats, either

So I have a certain function which I need to call only if a certain condition is true. If it's false, I consider it as Right.

I would use *EitherT.cond*, but the thing is my function's return type is *Future[Either[ErrorType, Unit]]*, so it's not suitable for me. Here's my code which does what I want:

```
def callEitherFunction: Future[Either[ErrorType, Unit]]

for {
_ <- if (condition) {
     EitherT(callEitherFunction)
   } else {
     Either.right[ErrorType, Unit](()).toEitherT[Future]
   }
} yield {
  //Some actions
}
```

I wonder if there is a more elegant way to do it. Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `EitherT.cond` as follows:

```
cond[Future](!condition, (), ()).leftFlatMap(_ => EitherT(callEitherFunction))
```

Also, `[Future]` can be omitted in some contexts, making it even shorter.

I'm not sure whether it's all that much clearer than the `if-else`, though: the slightly longer version with `if-else` might be easier to understand and to maintain in the long run.

---

Complete example with all imports:

```
import cats.data.EitherT
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.util.Either
import cats.syntax.either._
import cats.instances.future._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

type ErrorType = String
def callEitherFunction: Future[Either[ErrorType, Unit]] = ???
def condition: Boolean = true

EitherT.cond(!condition, (), ()).leftFlatMap(_ => EitherT(callEitherFunction))
```

Answer (score 3):

How about using `rightT` from `EitherT`?

```
for {
  _ <- if (condition) {
    EitherT(callEitherFunction)
  } else {
    EitherT.rightT[Future, ErrorType](())
  }
} yield {
  //Some actions
}
```